# "busy" state of angular directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

I want to create a directive that displays some data.

At some point I want the directive to signal to the context that is using it that it needs to get some fresh data (e.g. the user pressed some "more" button) I will do this by invoking a bound scope expression "moreClicked".

I assume that when this more button is clicked a round trip to a server will take place until the data to which the directive bound to will update and I would like to display some "busy" indicator until the data actually refreshes.

My Q is what would be a good pattern to implement such functionality?

Would It be true to claim that the directive can not know if it is indeed busy r not and that if it has some ui that represents that such a state it should also have a "busy" attribute that will allow binding and let the user of this directive change this value on its own?

Are there any other alternatives or considerations to make?

Comment: why not to add a "busy" parameter to your directive, watch it inside the directive and when it is true, disable the inputs in your directive (ng-disable) or disable the information as you like? And one more thing, i recommend you that your directives are completely self suficient, i mean, if you click on your directive, no to call other scope's function.

Comment: As I wrote, a busy attribute is exactly what I am considering.

What do you men when you say that the directive should be self suficient? would you expect the directive to make calls to the backend? I thought this was not a good or recommanded practice...

Comment: I think the busy attribute is a good idea, because the directive is a separate component of rest of your application, but it listens the changes on that attribute to interact.
I also think, if the purpose of the directive, is to make a request, the directve must do it, not every controller where this directive is used. It is a good idea if the directive uses a service whom it calls to make the request, that way each behaviour is where it has to be, and the directive calls the services but does not know how to make the request. This way you have many reusable encapsulated code.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly is 'context' and how the directive relates with others. Some code would help.